# delete folder with all content with php

Tags: php

I have main folder named "gallery". In this folder there are some sub folders like "animal", "tree", etc. folder "animal" contains some pictures and so on. suppose i want to delete "animal" folder with all pictures in it, how can do this? 
i tried-

```
rmdirr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."admin/gallery/animal");
```

but in server, it deleted the whole "gallery" folder with all in it. please tell me what i am doing wrong and also give me a solution. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using some third party library? `rmdirr()` doesn't seem to be a standard PHP function.

Comment: Are you trying to delete all the files in the folder, whilst keeping all the subfolders?

Comment: @Juhana - no, i am not using 3rd party library. http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php.

Comment: Ok, you might want to fix the typo in the question then.

Comment: @desbest - actually the subfolders are various photo galleries. when i click to delete some gallery, i want the gallery is to be deleted that is - the folder is deleted with all it's pics.

Answer (score 5):

If there are no subfolders you can use `glob()` to empty the directory before using `rmdir()`:

```
foreach( glob( "/path/to/dir/*.*" ) as $filename ) {
    unlink( $filename );
}

rmdir( "/path/to/dir" );
```

By the way, `rmdir()` shouldn't delete any files. It just fails if the directory isn't empty. You might want to make sure there's nothing else in your code that causes the parent directory to be wiped out.

Comment: I like this, just not 100% sure it handles files without period caracter.  Too lazy to try.

Comment: I assumed if the files are pictures they're all .jpg or .png... Can't be sure, though.

Comment: Use `glob("/path/to/dir/*")` then.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the directory recursively with a helper function:

```
rrmdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."admin/gallery/animal");

function rrmdir($path)
{
  return is_file($path)
    ? @unlink($path)
    : array_map('rrmdir', glob($path.'/*')) == @rmdir($path)
  ;
}
```

Comment: Oh that is really *hardcore*.

Answer (score 1):

When removing a desired directory, you must first remove the files within that directory.  Once that is complete, then you may remove the directory -- assuming you have the proper permissions.

Included below is code that removes the files in the directory and will then remove the specified directory itself:

```
<?php
$dirname = "animal";

function destroy($dir) {
    $mydir = opendir($dir);
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($mydir))) {
        if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            chmod($dir.$file, 0777);
            if(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
                chdir('.');
                destroy($dir.$file.'/');
                rmdir($dir.$file) or DIE("Unable to delete $dir$file");
            }else{
                unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("Unable to delete $dir$file");
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($mydir);
}

destroyDir($dirname);
?>
```